# Django: A form/way for the user to change the URL with its text input

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm trying to create a way for the user to change url such that if the current url is something like

```
website.com/section/part/this
```

if he inputs in a textbox 'hello', it will become

```
website.com/section/part/hello
```

Do I need to make a form and send `hello` as a parameter and then redirect the user to that page, or is there a easier/Django way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to play with JavaScript, detect changes to the textbox and reflect them in the form `action` argument. The way to do this also depends on the JavaScript framework you are willing to use, if any.

AFAIK there's no built-in feature provided by Django to make this easier.